# Re-Enable Full Disk Encryption

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and selected full disk encryption. The first few times I booted up I had to enter the password to decrypt the device. However, I had to fix the boot loader after installing windows on the secondary drive. I followed the directions on https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line to mount my encrypted partition before working on the boot loader. To work with the bootloader I followed the Purging & Reinstalling GRUB 2 section from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing . However I forgot to lock it after I finished. Since then I have not been prompted for my password when booting, and udisksctl doesnt recognize the partition as encrypted. How do I re-enable the full disk encryption? I am particularly confused because, in searching for a solution to this problem, what I have achieved, apparently, shouldn't be possible.

Additionally here is the output of lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0 953.4G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:3    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:4    0    32G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p2 259:5    0 899.5G  0 part
```

And here is the output of

```
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="036ed63c-f73c-4b2c-816a-48fcef86f059" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="52ed81c4-2bd2-4fd5-aa4d-f2d843f14019"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="A670-13AD" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="9b8e237d-1825-496c-8c73-900a61f96ffb"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="bf936c64-9283-486c-aa83-042678baa82e" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="LinuxSwap" PARTUUID="17200f21-c51c-4807-b0a9-8c075af8e04b"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="6CF382D6515740CC" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="Windows" PARTUUID="3d5d045f-7703-4c2d-a810-1d7b68b9bf0a"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up with this.  I've not used `udisksctl unlock` referenced in your link but... getting access to your encrypted data should never cause it to be decrypted *on disk*.  What is the output of `sudo blkid`?  Please [edit] your question to add it (don't comment).

Comment: I added the outputs of blkid and lsblk. I also added the instructions I followed when working on the boot-loader.